# Unreachable URL, on Facebook comments plugin. App ID is the right one... not sure what to do

Tags: facebook, iframe, meta-tags, facebook-comments

http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/193
is a web page where I have the comment iFrame on. Litteraly, the only things that change on the page are the description, and image id. Everything else is virtually the same.

http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/192

this page displays the error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

here are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="easroom:photo" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Escaping A Spinning Room | Photo" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo URL . "images/" . $photo->url ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="<?echo $photo->disc?>" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/<? echo    $this->picid?>" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{36532270688XXXX}"/>
```

and what they look like on the on my web page (X is there on purpose),

and this is what they look like on the finished page

```
<meta property="og:type" content="easroom:photo" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Escaping A Spinning Room | Photo" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/images/13479919974.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Barry looking at the city after a long night of drinking. Actor Michael Souto." /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/189" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{36532270688XXXX}"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

This is located right after the `<body>` tag

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=36532270688XXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And here is where the comments code is.

```
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/<? echo $this->picid ?>" data-num-posts="4" data-width="310" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

I tried using their debugger tools, but it won't scrape my website.

I'm having a lot of trouble with these facebook comments. If you guys have any great alternatives, and not Disqus, that would be great. free too lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your value for fb:app_id is incorrect, you have

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{365322706881496}"/>
```

It should be

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="365322706881496"/>
```

Try fixing that and see if [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) can access the page correctly afterwards

Comment: Okay, great! That got the debugger to work. It's strange, all the examples have the curly brackets in them. I'm going through it right now and addressing any issues that it highlights. Any tips? Suggestions to improve the Facebook integration?

Comment: THe curly braces probably say {app id} in the examples - the actual value needs to be just the app ID - the more accurate your metadata is the better the stories look on Facebook.com when people click the links and the more people come back to your site from those likes, that's the basic theory anyway :)

Comment: Thank you very much Igy for taking the time to view my question over. Peace!

Comment: Hey, the warnings went away, but then they came back! lol, I did make some changes to the app, but just added additional information. Is this normal?

Comment: http://www.escapingaspinningroom.com/photos/photo/211 url is one that doesn't work now. It won't scrape any of my web pages.